# Is the Jacobian bounded a.e?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, jacobian

In this [paper](http://siba-ese.unisalento.it/index.php/notemat/article/viewFile/643/488) first Corollary, I find:

> let $\Phi$ a map from $\mathbb R^d$, $d ≥ 1$, onto itself which is bi-
>   Lipschitz continuous, has an almost everywhere constant Jacobian, and maps
>   the unit ball onto the unit cube.

Is the jacobian of $\Phi^{-1}$ bounded almost everywhere?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can find on Evans, measure theory and fine properties of functions, that:

If $f, g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ are locally lipschitz continous, and if $Y = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n\ :\ g(f(x))\ =\ x \}$ then $Dg(f(x))Df(x)=I$ for $L^n$ almost every $x \in Y$.

In your case you have $g = f^{-1}$ thus $Y = \mathbb{R}^n$ and so $D(f^{-1}(f(x))D(f(x))= I$ for almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. And the claim follows.

Comment: That function is not lipschitz @Mokata

Comment: yeah, but if I don't  know how to use the fact that it is Lipschitz to prove ^^

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, could you explain better?

Comment: I get it Thank's..